# Reverse wild card lookup in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, wildcard

In my mongo collection i have record like this

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("64884e6b7346e734060cdbae"),
  "combinations" : [
    "IPHONE 13 PRO MAX * 256GB-*"
  ]
}
```

I need find this by searching by this search string "IPHONE 13 PRO MAX SR BLU 256GB-AFE"

```
db.getCollection("Collection").find({ combinations: {$elemMatch:{ $regex: /^IPHONE 13 PRO MAX SR BLUE 256GB-AFE$/ }} });
```

I tried many ways nothing came to a result.

if any one can help it will be nice

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe [$regexMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/) would help here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `"combinations"` holds *"globs"* that you want to `"$match"` against a given string.

I think this is a bit fragile, but here's one way to convert these *"globs"* into a *regex* and then use these to match the given string.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$combinations",
          "initialValue": false,
          "in": {
            "$or": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$regexMatch": {
                  "input": "IPHONE 13 PRO MAX SR BLU 256GB-AFE",
                  "regex": {
                    "$replaceAll": {
                      "input": "$$this",
                      "find": "*",
                      "replacement": ".*"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XpnqLN4bFBi).